# Getting and Error when changing an ACL via Powershell

Tags: powershell, permissions, acl, fileserver

I am working on a small script which mdifies the ACL on a folderby adding extra permissions; I adm getting the error while I execute "Set-ACL" command; please do let me know what I am doing wrong.

```
$AddAccessRule = New-Object security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrul("CREATOROWNER",@("ReadAndExecute,Synchronize"),"ContainerInherit,Objectinherit","Inheritonly","Allow")
$objacl = get-acl $FolderPath
$ObjAcl.AddAccessRule($AddAccessRule)
Set-acl $FolderPath $objacl
```

The follwoing error occurs , when i execute it;

Exception calling "AddAccessRule" with "1" argument(s): "Some or all identity references could not be translated."
At C:\Users\kakulva\Desktop\Scripts\CreatorOwner\ACL.ps1:10 char:1
+ $ObjAcl.AddAccessRule($AddAccessRule)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : IdentityNotMappedException

Let me know if any quetions or clarifications required.

Comment: there appear to be typos in your sample code, can you check it? For instance is `CREATOROWNER` accurate or is it `CREATOR OWNER`? The former is what you have, but it should be the latter.. unless that's the issue.

Comment: Thanks Mike its working now , yes there should be space in between.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works ( or at least doesn't return errors ):

```
$AddAccessRule = New-Object 'security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrulE'("CREATOR OWNER",@("ReadAndExecute,Synchronize"),"ContainerInherit,Objectinherit","Inheritonly","Allow")
$objacl = get-acl C:\A
$ObjAcl.AddAccessRule($AddAccessRule)
Set-acl -PATH C:\A $objacl
```