# Remote Administration of Local Permissions and Local Users/Groups

Tags: .net, powershell, permissions, file-permissions, remote-access

I'm trying to modify file permissions of remote machines with that remote machines' local users and groups.

```
$IDR = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount( 'RemoteServer\testaccount' )

$AccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule(
    $IDR,
    'FullControl',
    'ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit',
    'None',
    'Allow'
)

$Item = (Get-Item \\RemoteServer\share\folder\folder\file)
$ACL = $Item.GetAccessControl()
$ACL.AddAccessRule($AccessRule)
$Item.SetAccessControl($ACL)
```

Output: Exception calling "AddAccessRule" with "1" argument(s): "Some or all identity references could not be translated."

I understand that this means it can't find the 'Computer\testaccount' that I have it searching for. I'm able to modify the remote file permissions with Builtin* (Ex: Builtin\Administrators) users & groups but not with created accounts.

testaccount does exist on RemoteServer.

\\RemoteServer\testaccount does not work

Builtin\testaccount does not work

Local\testaccount does not work

testaccount does not work

I'm able to remove the local account from the local file permissions remotely through roughly the same way.

Is there anyway to add RemoteServer's non-builtin local users and groups into RemoteServer's local file permissions from my local workstation?

OR

How do I resolve the error mentioned above?

Workaround Edit:

I didn't want to have to do this but I was able to launch a PowerShell session with Win32_Process with all the data to apply the permissions. It works. But, this is not ideal because it won't work on systems that can't accept WMI. I would still like to know if it's possible to fix my original problem without this clunky workaround.

Comment: Have you tried the Set-Acl method here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14402317/getting-and-error-when-changing-an-acl-via-powershell

Comment: It won't get that far in the script. It's getting stuck on $ACL.AddAccessRule($AccessRule) with the error I mentioned.

Comment: AS for this... (this is not ideal because it won't work on systems that can't accept WMI.) --- this is why you want to level CIM/WSMAN vs WMI. WMI Security needs are finicky and rely on DCOM, which has its own issues regarding remote sessions. Use WMI for those hosts that can't handle CIM/WSMAN.

Comment: I should've switched over to CIM a while ago, so I changed it in this script. I may be assuming you mean earlier versions of windows that can't accept WMI, when I said "can't accept WMI" I meant our servers like our NetApp servers that don't have PowerShell because I'm initiating a PowerShell instance with WMI.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite an old question, however I just stumbled over exactly this issue.
The clue is you need to take the language of your local OS into consideration.
On a German System for instance you need to use

```
$IDR = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount( 'vordefiniert\testaccount' )
```

To get sure what to use exactly, you can set the permissions manually via GUI and then check via

```
$Item = (Get-Item "\\$computerName\C$\user\$userSamAccountName\desktop\testfile")
$ACL = (Get-Acl -Path $Item.FullName)
$ACL.getAccessRules(true, true, typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount))
```

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be a few things wrong with your code.

First of all, you have a typo

```
\\Computer\C$\user\username\desktop\testfile
```

but that should be

```
\\Computer\C$\users\username\desktop\testfile
```

('users' = plural).

Next, you are getting the Security.Principal.NTAccount using `Computer\testaccount`, but later on you are getting the file item using `username`.

This should work though:

```
# create the Full Control access rule for the user
$AccessRule = (New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule(
                [System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]"$computerName\$userSamAccountName",
                "FullControl", "ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow"))

# get the item you want to set the FullControl accessrule on.
# you need permissions for this of course..
$Item = (Get-Item "\\$computerName\C$\user\$userSamAccountName\desktop\testfile")
$ACL = (Get-Acl -Path $Item.FullName)
$ACL.AddAccessRule($AccessRule)
Set-Acl -Path $Item.FullName $ACL
```

Comment: The file path is retrieved dynamically in actual code so it will be correct. But in the example code for the file path I forgot the 's', my bad.
As mentioned above, I'm having issues with this error: Exception calling "AddAccessRule" with "1" argument(s): "Some or all identity references could not be translated.".
I wanted to find a way to allow my local machine resolve the IDR when adding the AccessRule to the ACL -> $ACL.AddAccessRule($AccessRule).

Comment: @KyleHewitt The error could also mean that the file currently has deleted user(s) in the ACL so it may have nothing to do with the new accessrule you are trying to set. Did you check that? Take it step by step. What does `[System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]"$computerName\$userSamAccountName"` display? and `$AccessRule` after creation? Can you set the accessrule manually on the computer?